# Cannot edit paste code in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

My VS code seems to be glitching because whenever I paste anything the cursor changes from the blinking '|' to the big box insert type cursor. Is this just a setting I can change?

here is the video of that :https://rb.gy/y4babx

Comment: The video shows Visual Studio not Visual Studio Code!

Comment: You seem to have toggled Insert/Overwrite (may be by catching the `Insert` key) to overwrite the text. Notice the OVR in the bottom right of the editor window. Press it again to return to "insert" mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be your keybinds(if you used the insert button in your keybinds that is) or some plugin you use.

Answer (score 0):

This action is known as "Toggle Insert/ Overwrite". You need to check your keymaps in settings.